# Can DAO smart contracts be used to handle issues such as centralized manipulation or initial token distribution?

Tags: solidity, audit

I wrote an ERC20 smart contract extending standard openzepplein `ERC20.sol`. While Certik audit, it exposes centralized manipulation and initial token distribution issues.
I am wondering if I can handle these issues by using DAO smart contract.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, DAO (Decentralized Autonomous Organization) smart contracts can be used to address issues such as centralized manipulation and initial token distribution.

By implementing a DAO, you can create a decentralized governance structure that allows token holders to have a say in decision-making processes, reducing the potential for manipulation.
Additionally, DAOs can provide transparent and automated processes for token distribution, ensuring fairness and accountability.